# Join two tables on one without mutyplying rows per record

Tags: sql, oracle

Let say we have 3 tables named `TRANSACTIONS`, `ORDERS`, `PAYMENTS` all of them having `TRANSACTION_ID`.

This is the regular output I get when joining transaction that has 5 orders and 3 payments:

```
transaction_id, order_id, payment_id
----------
1, 20, 35
1, 20, 36
1, 20, 37
1, 21, 35
1, 21, 36
1, 21, 37
....
```

What I should get is:

```
transaction_id, order_id, payment_id
----------
1, 20, 35
1, 21, 36
1, 22, 37
1, 23, null
1, 24, null
```

If there are more payments than orders, it should have `NULL` in the `order_id` column.

Basically I need to have number of rows per `transaction_id` equal to the bigger number of count of `orders`/`payments` (in this example 5 > 3 so 5).

Have in mind that each of these tables have couple of million records.

**EDIT**:

By the request in the comment, above query is simple join

```
SELECT t.transaction_id, o.order_id, p.payment_id
FROM TRANSACTION t
LEFT JOIN ORDERS o on o.transaction_id = t.transaction_id
LEFT JOIN PAYMENTS p on p.transaction_id = o.transaction_id
```

**EDIT 2**:

I cannot disclose full table schemes, I only wrote columns essential for the query to work. In reality every of those tables has 20+ columns, and the query should return a combined total of around 20 columns.
Again, `TRANSACTIONS` has over 100m records, and both `ORDERS` and `PAYMENTS` have 150m+ records of which we need around 100k records to be returned.

Comment: Can you post your SQL query?

Comment: Could you show tables example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should union both results and check rows for it like below :

```
select transaction_id, sum(order_id) as order_id, sum(payment_id) as payment_id
from
(
    SELECT t.transaction_id, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.transaction_id ORDER BY order_id) RowNo, 
           o.order_id, 
           null as payment_id
    FROM TRANSACTIONS t
    LEFT JOIN ORDERS o on o.transaction_id = t.transaction_id

    union 

    SELECT t.transaction_id, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.transaction_id ORDER BY payment_id) RowNo, 
           null as order_id, 
           p.payment_id
    FROM TRANSACTIONS t
    LEFT JOIN Payments p on p.transaction_id = t.transaction_id
) tt
group by transaction_id, RowNo
```

SQL Fiddle Demo : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e991d/21

**UPDATE :**

Please try it with JOIN instead of UNION like below :

```
SELECT t1.transaction_id, t1.order_id, t2.payment_id
from   
(
  SELECT t.transaction_id, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.transaction_id ORDER BY order_id) RowNo,
         o.order_id
  FROM TRANSACTIONS t
  LEFT JOIN ORDERS o on o.transaction_id = t.transaction_id
) t1
full join 
(
  SELECT t.transaction_id, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.transaction_id ORDER BY p.payment_id) RowNo,
         p.payment_id
  FROM TRANSACTIONS t
  LEFT JOIN Payments p on p.transaction_id = t.transaction_id
  ) t2
on t1.transaction_id = t2.transaction_id and t1.RowNo = t2.RowNo
```

SQL Fiddle Demo : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e991d/20

Comment: Solution works but ``UNION`` makes it is very slow. Can you think of another way that would not force two passes? I'll vote up the answer because it does what it should.

Comment: You forgot to add ``partition by transaction_id``.
This has almost the same cost as ``UNION``, but it is better.
I'll mark this as an answer in a day if no one comes up with more optimized solution.

Comment: Sorry, I missed it, I have updated my answer. Please check now.

Comment: Also in terms of performance, 2nd query is better. I have checked with sample 1 million records in my local DB and found that 1st query takes 74 secs to execute while 2nd query takes only 4 secs.

Comment: Have you found any other best solution except my answer ? please give your feedback

Comment: Sorry, I don't work over weekends. I'll select this as an answer now.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should add one extra RowNumber column (using [ROW_NUMBER() OVER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm)) to the `Orders` and `Payments` tables and then join them with this column.

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/973e7/20)

```
select tr.transaction_id, 
       Orders.order_id,
       Payments.payment_id

from TRANSACTIONS tr

LEFT JOIN 
(
select transaction_id,order_id,
       ROW_NUMBER() 
       OVER (PARTITION BY transaction_id ORDER BY order_id) as rn
FROM ORDERS
) Orders on tr.transaction_id=Orders.transaction_id

LEFT JOIN 
(
select transaction_id,payment_id,
       ROW_NUMBER() 
       OVER (PARTITION BY transaction_id ORDER BY payment_id) as rn
FROM PAYMENTS
) Payments on (tr.transaction_id=Payments.transaction_id)
                  AND (Orders.rn=Payments.rn)

UNION 

select tr.transaction_id, 
       Orders.order_id,
       Payments.payment_id

from TRANSACTIONS tr

LEFT JOIN 
(
select transaction_id,payment_id,
       ROW_NUMBER() 
       OVER (PARTITION BY transaction_id ORDER BY payment_id) as rn
FROM PAYMENTS
) Payments on (tr.transaction_id=Payments.transaction_id)

LEFT JOIN 
(
select transaction_id,order_id,
       ROW_NUMBER() 
       OVER (PARTITION BY transaction_id ORDER BY order_id) as rn
FROM ORDERS
) Orders on tr.transaction_id=Orders.transaction_id
            AND (Orders.rn=Payments.rn)
```

Another way is here without union. In this case we need to generate sequence 1,2,3,4.... and then JOIN both tables joining also with RowNumber to this sequence. In this example we generate sequence from 1 to 1000 (`CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000`). If you don't know what is the maximum rows count possible then you can generate sequence using `select COUNT() ...` from both tables as a maximum number for sequence generator.

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/973e7/46)

```
select tr.transaction_id, 
       Orders.order_id,
       Payments.payment_id

from TRANSACTIONS tr
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT LEVEL as rn
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000
) Cnt  

LEFT JOIN 
(
select transaction_id,order_id,
       ROW_NUMBER() 
       OVER (PARTITION BY transaction_id ORDER BY order_id) as rn
FROM ORDERS
) Orders on (tr.transaction_id=Orders.transaction_id)
            AND 
            (cnt.rn=Orders.rn )

LEFT JOIN 
(
select transaction_id,payment_id,
       ROW_NUMBER() 
       OVER (PARTITION BY transaction_id ORDER BY payment_id) as rn
FROM PAYMENTS
) Payments on (tr.transaction_id=Payments.transaction_id)
            AND 
            (cnt.rn=Payments.rn)

WHERE Payments.payment_id IS NOT NULL or 
      Orders.Order_id IS NOT NULL 
order by tr.transaction_id,cnt.rn
```

Comment: I was about to edit my question and add similar query i wrote. This works **but** it will not work if you have more ``payments`` than ``orders``.

Comment: @DusanVasiljevic I've edit the query. I've added UNION to process both cases.

Comment: Unfortunately, we would like to avoid using ``UNION`` since it has big cost, and tables are really huge. I'll vote up since it gives good results, but I'm looking for something more optimal.

Comment: @DusanVasiljevic I've added one more query and example without UNION.